# Casting a phone screen using fiberglass resin?

Tags: casting, composite-resin

My phone is pretty smashed up and I won't be able to buy a new one for quite a while. I know you can buy a phone for ~$30, but I'm in an extremely tight situation and I just can't afford that right now. I do, however, have some Protite (clear-casting/embedding) fibreglass resin and catalyst. So my question is, if I were to cast a (temporary) new screen, how safe would it be to use? Would I even be able to attach it to the digitiser without losing functionality? And, if anyone could even approximate, how long could I expect it to last?  I know an epoxy bond would be stronger but aside from that I'm not sure how it would go enduring heat from the phone, or if it might pose any other risks. I live an hour out of town and rely on my phone greatly, it's kind of essential, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

*NB: I posted here because I felt this query pertained most to 'a specific engineering problem' and didn't fit the criteria for the electrical engineering site, nor do I believe it is specific to a particular type of device e.g. iPhone or Android. I apologise if that is not correct. I'm new to SE and definitely no expert in such matters.*

Comment: Put a protective screen on top? How will resin allow the touch sensiing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. NMech raised the question of how it might affect a capacitative or resistive touch screen, which led me to the conclusion that it won't work with my particular phone - the reason being that it uses a capacitative screen and fiberglass is not conductive. I've seen it done before on a resistive screen using epoxy, but never fiberglass, so in that instance I'm not sure if it would have a significant effect or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be  assuming that you are talking about a "smartphone".

**To be honest, if your phone is marginally working, and you are strapped for cash, I would avoid doing so.**

Having said that, I'd be very interested to hear what the results of this experiment is.

To be honest, I'd expect that you would probably brick the phone if you tried that. The heat from the phone is not the problem (if its a resin, its most likely a thermosetting one, so there is no worry about it having a problem).

The main problem (IMHO), is that you'd be adding an very stiff layer on top of your screen. Even if its a tenth of a mm, it would be orders of magnitude stiffer than the film you use. The end result would be, that you'd be applying the force over a bigger area. So the responsiveness of the phone would degrade - a lot.

Having said that, you'd probably encounter other problems should you try to go down that road. e.g. Chemical reactions. you might find that the resin, bonds to the screen.

Also something another question is, how will a capacitative or resistive touch screen behave in this scenario?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am referring to a smartphone, yes. I guess I'm better off just waiting until I can afford a new one. Like I said, I'm definitely not an expert but I can see how that could be an issue. I figure there's a good reason I couldn't find any examples using fiberglass resin.

I'm not certain, but I think there's a chance it could work with resistive since those consist of a plastic layer on glass. Unfortunately my phone uses capacitative, which relies on conductivity, and fiberglass isn't conductive.

I may give it a go anyway when I do get a replacement because, why not?

Comment: I feel like I should note I'll get a spare phone with a resistive screen to try, haha.

Comment: I think that's the most prudent way to go...